# Strip hashtags from string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have a string that may contains Twitter hashtags. I'd like to strip it from the string. How should I do this? I'm trying to use the RegExp class but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
var regexp = new RegExp('\b#\w\w+');
postText = postText.replace(regexp, '');
```

Comment: please put an example of input

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
postText = 'this is a #test of #hashtags';
var regexp = /#\S+/g;
postText = postText.replace(regexp, 'REPLACED');
```

This uses the 'g' attribute which means 'find ALL matches', instead of stopping at the first occurrence.

Comment: I think the \b needs to be in there otherwise urls such as 'http://twitter.com/#search=' will incorrectly get picked up as hash tags

Answer (score 5):

You can write:

```
// g denotes that ALL hashags will be replaced in postText    
postText = postText.replace(/\b\#\w+/g, '');
```

I don't see a reson for the first `\w`. The `+` sign is used for one or more occurences. (Or are you interested only in hashtags with two characters?)

> g enables "global" matching. When using the replace() method, specify this modifier to replace all matches, rather than only the first one.

Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

This?

```js
postText = "this is a #bla and a #bla plus#bla"
var regexp = /\#\w\w+\s?/g
postText = postText.replace(regexp, '');
console.log(postText)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The only one of these regex's that actually works as described. Thumbs up. :D

Comment: can you please improve it so it stops at full-stop also? thanks

Comment: @Toolkit what do you mean? Replace `"This is a #bla and a #bla plus#bla."` to `"This is a and a plus."` ? It does that already